# Why do not my secondary Databases connect in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a Ruby On Rails application that uses two databases at the same time. One of those databases is the same always but the other one is dynamically changed if you select a different project.

I have a .yml database configuration file for each one:

MAINdb.yml (never changed)

project_1.yml

project_2.yml

...

project_n.yml

If you change the project, a new .yml is read and the DB connection is changed in runtime.

.yml example:

```
  default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 30 } %>
  encoding: unicode
  username: xxx
  password: xxx
  timeout: 2400
  port: 5432

development:
  <<: *default
  host: xx.xx.xx.xx
  database: development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: development

production:
  <<: *default
  host: xx.xx.xx.xx
  database: production
```

Well, I have a "hybrid connection" because of a need to use a lot of tables from MAINdb and 3 o 4 tables from secondary db.

I make this secondary connection as you can see here:

```
class AuxDbBase < ActiveRecord::Base  
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

Model example:

```
class Example< AuxDbBase
    self.table_name ="example"
end
```

Dinammic connection:

```
connection_db_params = YAML::load(ERB.new(File.read(Rails.root.join("config/db_config", "#{project}.yml"))).result)[Rails.env]
Example.establish_connection connection_db_params
```

All of then is working in development mode, but in production mode, I have this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: there is no "example" relationship
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE type = 'xxx'
```

Does anyone know where the source of the problem may be?

What can change when it comes to the migrating environment for this to be happening?

I am thankful for any kind of help

Sorry for my English

Comment: looks like the databases are different. In your case relationship is absent on database.

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: are you sure each database has 'examples' table? Did you run migration on all of them?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I am using the same databases but in development mode rigth now. I have verified that in local (windows - puma) the databases are working in production mode, but in the servers (CentOS / unicorn + nginx) not. The database change it is not working

Comment: if 'host' is localhost change it to 127.0.0.1

Comment: No, no localhost. I have the aplication in 2 distributed servers whit his IPs. Local is my develpment computer, and app is work here in production mode and in all modes, but not on servers.